# [SPO 2013]Most efficient place to store asset files?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a page that Im using to display various content through a combination of REST calls.  Originally I had my image, css, and js files stored in Site Assets, but ended up moving them to Style Library as the performance seems to be a bit better.  Still, some images, even those ~5kb, have sporadic loading times ranging from the expected few MS to several seconds.  These load times vary for all files each time I load my page. Sometimes File A will load quickly and File B will take 5+ seconds.  The next time I refresh the page File A will take 5+ seconds and File B will load quickly (caching accounted for).

Does anyone know if there are any places within SP that allow for more efficient loading times than Style Library or Site Assets?  Or is this just something that is inherent to a SPO environment?

Comment: I think file size will have a larger impact on load times.  Don't see why location would impact anything other than permissions and ease of use.

Comment: Look at this article. It explains part of your problem and perhaps one of the solutions proposed will fit your needs: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2009/05/optimization-blob-caching-and-http-304s.html

Answer (score 0):

Both of those are internal libraries handled the same.  When you store your assets in those libraries they are actually being stored in a database.  So when accessing them, behind the scenes there are some DB queries happening to grab the document and hand them off to SharePoint and then present to you.  to be honest I don't think I've ever had an issue pulling assets from either.

You can look at using a service to concatenate and minify your assets.  That alone may be enough to get you the response times you are looking for.

If you need to get more speed you probably need to look at a different option outside of O365.  You can upload to another hosting service or use MS Azure.  The speed of delivery will then really depend on the service itself and the latency of your network between you and the service.

Comment: I think you may be right that the solution may be to host the assets outside of SP, which is unfortunate.  The assets have been compressed/minified, but Im still seeing unusually long load times for very small files (~5 sec for ~5kb).  The part that makes me think its due to SP rather than the file itself is that the file load times vary between page loads.